# Why is the last panel on a new line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, panels

I'm having some problem with bootstrap 3.0 using panels and cols.
When the page goes full screen I would like to have the last panel just below the first one rather than having it in a whole new line to decrease the scrolling for the users that uses it. How can I achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/39q8yxrv/

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <strong>Personal details</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">
                <strong>Field</strong>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    Male
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <strong>Personal details</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">
                <strong>Field</strong>
            </label>

            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    Male
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <strong>Personal details</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">
                <strong>Field</strong>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    Male
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">
                <strong>Field</strong>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    Male
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">
                <strong>Field</strong>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    Male
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">
                <strong>Field</strong>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    Male
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">
                <strong>Field</strong>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    Male
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <strong>Personal details</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">
                <strong>Field</strong>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    Male
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're closing every one of your `<div class="panel panel-default">` elements before you add their bodies... Should look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/39q8yxrv/2/

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't see it I was in a hurry when I wrote the example thanks for the correction bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's grid is 12 columns, you have 16. change `col-sm-4`, `col-md-4` to `col-sm-3` and `col-md-3` to fit in 12 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/39q8yxrv/1/

You just need to stack the two panels in the same column.  Your current layout has 4 columns (col-md-4), each with a width of 33%, which exceeds 100% total width.  So, your last column is getting pushed below the others. However, your first column will contain both panels if set up like:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel">panel 1...</div>
    <div class="panel">panel 2...</div>
</div>
```

You might also want to take another look at bootstrap's docs on panels: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels.  Your panel heading and body should be inside of the main panel div.  As you have it now, your panel-body is outside of the panel container.  If you are using the panel heading for the gray background style, you may want to consider just using the .well class (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#wells).

Another observation -

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
```

This is redundant.  You only need to use col-sm-4, which would apply to small screens and above.  If you needed to change the layout on larger screens, only then would you need to define another class, so for example:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-6"></div>
```

Would span 12 columns on extra-small screens, 4 columns on small and medium screens, and 6 columns on large and above.

Comment: Consider changing your code to the following: http://jsfiddle.net/39q8yxrv/3/ Panels were being closed too early.

Comment: Thank you very much but in fact I would like to have the panel pilled the same way you've shown but without having to do the separation do you see what I mean...? Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't want the boxes around the sections, then you probably don't want to use panels.  Just give your headings the "well" class, or another class to style accordingly.

Comment: I think we did not understand each other haha. 
I will use the column to separate the panels thanks sista :-)
Regards

Comment: Finally not let's come back to this example : http://jsfiddle.net/39q8yxrv/2/
You can see that the panel located at the new line is under the third panel height what I would like to have is to have the panel alone just under the first not far in height how can I achieve this...?

Comment: Did my original answer not answer your question?  The 4th panel needs to be in the same column as the first panel if you want it to be directly below the first panel.  See the jsfiddle from my answer.  Then, @TimLewis updated the fiddle using the panels correctly and in the layout you were requesting.  Are you looking for something different?

Comment: To summarize what I would like to have this result http://jsfiddle.net/mvrg57xc/ but without having to use the "columning" fonctionallity because if I avoid the "columning" I end up with this result http://jsfiddle.net/39q8yxrv/2/ is it possible in bootstrap...? In fact I would like bootstrap to do it manually :) I think I'm asking too much isn't it...?